# Why a virtualized file system for in-browser trusted-mode SL5 apps?

Tags: silverlight

In Silverlight 5, applications can access the file system without restriction via FileInfo and related classes when running with elevated privileges. Also since SL5, an app can run inside the browser with elevated trust.

However, when running in-browser, all access to the file system appears to end up being routed to a special directory *AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Virtualized\C...*.

This is a different behavior from running without elevated trust altogether, which throws a SecurityException. Out-of-browser, the behavior is as expected.

Note that in all cases I run the app through visual studio, which is, as far as in-browser support is concerned, all I'm interested in.

Is this desired behavior? Can I change it?

Comment: As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx, are you running as a "Trusted Application"? You didn't list how you elevated your privileges.

Comment: @JoelLucsy I run with requiring elevated trust both inside and outside the browser. I'm not sure what different concept "elevated privileges" should be as referred to by your link. The API even has a third term, "elevated permissions", which appears to be equivalent to "elevated trust". I'm fixing my question.

Comment: I just ran into this and it's driving me nuts. I don't see this behavior documented anywhere...

Comment: It appears to only happen when I'm testing the application through Visual Studio via a localhost:31234 address. It seems to work fine after I put it on our web server and accessed it like a normal website.

Comment: @MikeMarynowski That could be the case. You can easily use IIS Express within VS, maybe that's fixing the issue for development also.

Comment: @John That is though IIS Express. It goes through a localhost address when you use IIS Express.